# Inject services to src/groovy in Grails 3.0.9

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.0.9

I am trying to create an EndPoint file. So I created a file with name `ServerEndPointDemo.groovy`

```
package com.akiong

import grails.util.Environment
import grails.util.Holders

import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig
import javax.websocket.OnClose
import javax.websocket.OnError
import javax.websocket.OnMessage
import javax.websocket.OnOpen
import javax.websocket.Session
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam
import javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint
import javax.websocket.EncodeException

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet

@WebListener
@ServerEndpoint(value="/chat/test/{username}")

public class ServerEndPointDemo implements ServletContextListener {
    private static HashMap<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static final Set<ServerEndPointDemo> connections = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
    private String username
    private Session session

    @OnOpen
    public void  handleOpen(Session session,@PathParam("username") String user){
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection");
        println "user = "+user

        connections.add(this);
        this.username   = user
        this.session    = session

        addUserToMap(username,session.getId())

        try{
            def ctx = Holders.applicationContext
            chatService = ctx.chatService
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            println "e = "+e
        }

    }

    @OnClose
    public void  handleClose(Session session){  
        System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");  
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String message,Session session){
        chatService.saveSessionAdminJava(session.getId())    
    }

    @OnError
    public void  handleError(Throwable t){
        println "error ~"
    }  

    private void sendMessageToAll(String message){
        println "session.size() = "+sessions.size()
        for(Session s : sessions){
            try {
                s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
                println "sent to session = "+s.getId()
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
`
```

I tried to use this code for calling a method from service:

```
try {
    def ctx = Holders.applicationContext
    chatService = ctx.chatService
} catch (Exception e) {
    println "e = " + e
}
```

This is my service:

```
package com.akiong.services

import com.akiong.maintenance.Chat

class ChatService {

    def serviceMethod() {

    }

    def saveSessionAdminJava(def sessionJava) {
        println "jaln!!!"
        def chatInstance = Chat.findByIsAdmin("1")
        chatInstance.sessionJava = sessionJava
        chatInstance.save(failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

But after I tried to run this code, I'm getting this error:

```
Error : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: chatService for
class: com.akiong.ServerEndPointDemo
```

Anyone know how to call a method from service to file in `src/groovy`?

Comment: does the existing plugin confuse you ? since wschat is doing all of this, instead of defining the classes in the main class it gets intialised in ChatUtils.groovy but then injected in WsChatEndPoint.. The reason for that is that that EndPoint + the other 4 other endPoints all extend that ChatUtils class in effect saving me time declaring over and over again the same content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the problem. The code you written is correct for injecting service:

```
try {
    def ctx = Holders.applicationContext
    chatService = ctx.chatService
} catch (Exception e) {
    println "e = "+e
}
```

But the `chatService` is not defined anywhere in your class. So even if your `handleOpen` method is invoked there must be `MissingPropertyException` being thrown but since you have handled the top level `Exception` class (**which should never be encouraged**) that exception from your `handleOpen` method got suppressed.

Now, later in your `handleMessage` method, the same problem is occurring again of `chatService` being undefined and hence you are getting the exception you posted in your question.

So, you know the answer now :-) Simply define the `chatService` in your `ServerEndPointDemo` class.

**Update:**

```
public class ServerEndPointDemo implements ServletContextListener {
    private static HashMap<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static final Set<ServerEndPointDemo> connections = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
    private String username
    private Session session

    def chartService    // Initialize here
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: No this is wrong. You are defining inside the `try-catch` so it's scope will be limited to just there. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

class MyClass{
    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
    def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
    def authService=ctx.authService

    def method(){
        log.debug "into MyClass method"
    }
}
```

Comment: ` org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
 @ line 20, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH
   ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\309\bola309\src\main\groovy\com\akiong\ServerEndPointDem
o.groovy: 34: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.Applica
tionHolder
 @ line 34, column 15.
       def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
                 ^

2 errors`